# How to count and do calculation column by specific value using DAX in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, calculation

I am new with powerbi. I would like to count how many column that has X value.
then do calculation.
The condition is calculate the column from `PC` to `RPOS` with contain of `X` value. Then, calculate the `FINAL` table with this condition: if the RESULT table has `X` value, then the `total column * 10`, if the `RESULT` table does not has `X` value, then the `total column * 5`

anyone can give me idea please. I really appreciated it. Thank you.

Here what I tried,
I tried create  a new column, then calculate the total column, I used the new column to get the FINAL table calculation, but it return this error

```
A circular dependency was detected
```

[image]

Here is the DAX:
This is the calculation of the column

```
TotalColumn = CALCULATE(COUNT('Data'[PC]) + COUNT('Data'[NB]) + COUNT('Data'[DT]) + COUNT('Data'[OAI]) + COUNT('Data'[RPOS]))
```

This is the calculation of tabel `FINAL`

```
FINAL = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE()
    ,'Data'[Result]="X",[TotalColumn] * 100
    ,[TotalColumn] / 4 * 100
)
```

Comment: Can you please add your dax code here?

Comment: `[TotalColumn]` if this is a measure or calculated column then a code is needed

Comment: @Mik ya, its calculated column

Comment: I'll check the formula in 10 min

Comment: try to change the calc column code as in the answer. It should work, I hope )

Comment: @Mik so I don't need to change the calculation of final table?

Comment: If you can replace Xs with some dummy value and fill the Final column with your expected value, this will make things more clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try the measure with CALCULATE like this:

```
TotalColumn = 
VAR PC = 'Data'[PC]
VAR NB = 'Data'[NB]
VAR DT = 'Data'[DT]
VAR OAI = 'Data'[OAI]
VAR RPOS = 'Data'[RPOS]
VAR Result = 'Data'[RESULT]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Data'[PC]) + COUNT('Data'[NB]) + COUNT('Data'[DT]) 
        + COUNT('Data'[OAI]) + COUNT('Data'[RPOS])
        ,'Data'[PC]=PC
        ,'Data'[NB]=NB
        ,'Data'[DT]=DT
        ,'Data'[OAI]=OAI
        ,'Data'[RPOS]=RPOS
        ,'Data'[RESULT]=Result
        ,ALL()
        )
```

ALL() works first (due to DAX priorities) and removes all filters, then reapply all Filters with Values

Comment: its not what I need :(

Comment: its incorrect, the result of TotalColumn is not correct. It supposed to be 0 to 4, but the value is all the row are the same and the value is 37

Comment: add Result Value. And you don't need to change FINAL

Comment: sounds strange. I have to go. Let me think about it tomorrow.

Comment: I added, but the result is still incorrect value, not 0 to 4

Comment: I know the problem is, it calculate another column, not only PC, NB, DT, OAI, RPOS, if another column not blank, than it include to calculate, but my expectation only calculate those 5 column @Mik

Comment: HI, is [TotalColumn]  in the same table? Why it's not represented on the picture?